# Pythonでファイル名一覧を速く取得したい

Tags: python

CD-ROMのファイル名一覧（ディレクトリ名はいらない）を取得したいと思っています。

```
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob(‘e:/**’,recursive=True) //処理1
fileonly = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)] //処理2
```

こんな感じで一覧取得できるのですがリスト内包表記を行なっている部分の処理が時間がかかります。
time.time()で計測すると、336のファイル及びディレクトリから323のファイルのみを取り出す操作に、
処理1：1.78秒、処理2：2.72秒かかります。特に2の処理を短縮したいです。

何かコードを見直す方法がありますでしょうか？

Comment: こちらの記事 [How to find files and skip directories in os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22207936/9014308) の解決マーク付き回答の後半に書かれている `glob.glob` を使わずに `os.scandir` だけを使って1段階で処理をするのが早いらしいですよ。あと類似の話題・方法を扱った日本語の記事がこちら。[Pythonのディレクトリ内のすべてのサブディレクトリを一覧表示します](https://www.techiedelight.com/ja/list-all-subdirectories-in-directory-python/) 内容的にはファイルではなくディレクトリを検出していますが、逆に判定すればファイルだけに出来るでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。ファイル名一覧が欲しくて、いろいろ悩んでいました。解決法がいろいろあり今後の参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントにある通り、1段階で処理をすると早く終わります。ただ、ディレクトリを再帰的にたどる記述の分、`glob` に比べるとコードが増えます。[`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.html#os.walk) を使うと、やや簡潔になるかと思います。

下のコードは、`glob` を使用した質問のコードと異なり、ディレクトリへのシンボリックリンクをたどりません。また `os.path.isfile` はシンボリックリンクをたどってチェックしますが、下ではそのような処理は有りませんので、リンク先が存在しないシンボリックファイルなども結果に含まれます。

```
import os

root = os.getcwd()
files = []
for parent, _, child_files in os.walk(root):
    for f in child_files:
        files.append(os.path.join(parent, f))
```

---

追記:

#### 高速になる理由

上で処理が早く終わる理由は、使用している構文とは関係ありません。今回の処理内容ですと、内包表記に適したAPIは無さそうなので使用していませんが、内包表記で書けるのなら、それでも速度に大きな影響は無いはずです。

今回の処理で時間がかかる部分はIO（ファイルへのアクセス）ですので、これを最小限にすることが大事です。ディレクトリ内のファイルのリストを得るとともに、それらのファイルがディレクトリなのか否かの情報も取得できれば、再度 `os.path.isfile` などでアクセスするより効率的です。これを冒頭では「1段階」と表現しました。

よって、上のようなことが可能なAPIを選択します。例えば `os.scandir()` です。`os.walk()` も内部で `os.scandir()` を使用しています。

> `listdir()` の代わりに `scandir()` を使用すると、ファイルタイプや属性情報も必要とするコードのパフォーマンスが大幅に向上します。これは、オペレーティングシステムがディレクトリのスキャン中にこの情報を提供した場合、`os.DirEntry` オブジェクトがその情報を公開するからです。すべての `os.DirEntry` メソッドはシステムコールを実行する場合がありますが、`is_dir()` と `is_file()` は、通常はシンボリックリンクにしかシステムコールを必要としません。
>
> [os —— os.scandir()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)

Comment: mjy様
ご回答ありがとうございました。爆速になりました。
forで回してリストにappendするのはとても速いですね。
リスト内包表記は見た目はかっこいいんですがスピードという面では犠牲になりますね。この度はありがとうございました。

Comment: @masa さん、一般的にはリスト内包表記の方が早いらしいので、行っている処理の内容とCD-ROMという装置/媒体を扱っていることによる特殊事情では？ [【Python】リスト内包表記は本当に速いのか](https://skill-sharing.info/archives/374), [【第23回】リスト内包表記による処理時間の高速化](https://chantastu.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/09/24/024602), [【Python】結局、リスト内包表記は速いのか？](https://blog.minatoproject.com/?p=1411)

Comment: @kunif さん。確かにどの入門書を見てもリスト内包表記を使いましょうとなっています。状況に合わせて使い分けていきたいと思います。